# Comparação SQL com valores escritos de formas diferentes

Tags: sql

Estou comparando duas tabelas "A" e "B" em que quero comparar valores das colunas com o mesmo significado,porém estão escritas de formas diferentes.
A tabela "A" possui a coluna "Mes_ano" e possui valores "jan,fev,mar,abr..." enquanto que na tabela "B" possui coluna "Meses_promoção" e possui valores aleatórios de 01 a 12.
Como posso fazer essas correlações via SQL pegando "Funcionario_mes" da tabela "A" quando "fev" da tabela A corresponde a "02" da tabela "B"?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
O resultado do SQL deveria trazer apenas os meses citados na tabela "B". Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: qual SGDB você está utilizando ?

Comment: Pesquise por CASE.

Comment: Resolveu sua questão ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Queria entender o porque de armazenar 'jan' em uma coluna no banco de dados, puts... mas, vamos lá:

Você pode fazer um `Case When` diretamente na query, ou criar uma função para isso, como imagino que terá de utilizar novamente em outras querys, a função é o mais indicado:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[mesFromName]
(
    @mes Varchar(20)
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN
        CASE 
            WHEN @mes like 'jan%' THEN 1
            WHEN @mes like 'fev%' THEN 2
            WHEN @mes like 'mar%' THEN 3
            WHEN @mes like 'abr%' THEN 4
            WHEN @mes like 'mai%' THEN 5
            WHEN @mes like 'jun%' THEN 6
            WHEN @mes like 'jul%' THEN 7
            WHEN @mes like 'ago%' THEN 8
            WHEN @mes like 'set%' THEN 9
            WHEN @mes like 'out%' THEN 10
            WHEN @mes like 'nov%' THEN 11
            WHEN @mes like 'dez%' THEN 12
            ELSE 0
        END 

END
```

Após isso, basta fazer o join pelas tabelas, utilizando a função:

```
Select
a.mes, 
a.funcionario,
case 
    when p.mes is null then 
        'Não' 
    else 
   'Sim' 
End  as teve_promocao
from tabelaa a 
left outer join promocao p on dbo.mesFromName(a.mes) = p.mes;
```

Espero ter ajudado. E não se esqueça de marcar como resposta.

Coloquei no SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ded9d/5

Comment: Na verdade,criei um exemplo qualquer que é similar com o problema que tinha,por isso os nomes 'jan','fev' rs.
Mas adaptei a ideia e consegui resolver o problema! Obrigado.